# Memory leak debugging: Ignore false positives (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I am able to split the Visual Studio memory leak report in false positives and real memory leaks. **In my main function, I initialize the memory debugging and generate a real memory leak at the really beginning of my application** (never delete pcDynamicHeapStart):

```
int main()
{   
   _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF );
   char* pcDynamicHeapStart = new char[ 17u ];
   strcpy_s( pcDynamicHeapStart, 17u, "DynamicHeapStart" );

   ...
```

After my application is finished, the report at the output window contains:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{15554} normal block at 0x00000000009FCCD0, 80 bytes long.
Data: <                > DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD
{14006} normal block at 0x00000000009CB360, 17 bytes long.
Data: <DynamicHeapStart> 44 79 6E 61 6D 69 63 48 65 61 70 53 74 61 72 74 
{13998} normal block at 0x00000000009BF4B0, 32 bytes long.
Data: < ^              > E0 5E 9B 00 00 00 00 00 F0 7F 9C 00 00 00 00 00 
{13997} normal block at 0x00000000009CA4B0, 8 bytes long.
Data: <        > 14 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
{13982} normal block at 0x00000000009A12C0, 16 bytes long.
Data: <   @            > D0 DD D6 40 01 00 00 00 90 08 9C 00 00 00 00 00

...

Object dump complete.
```

Now look at line "Data: <**DynamicHeapStart**> 44 79 6E 61 6D 69 63 48 65 61 70 53 74 61 72 74".

**All reportet leaks below are false positives, all above are real leaks.**
False positives don't mean there is no leak (it could be a static linked library which allocates heap at startup and never frees it), but you cannot eliminate the leak and that's no problem at all.

Since I invented this approach, I never had leaking applications any more.

**I wonder if I could hide the false positives** (or leaks from statically allocated objects). My report contains hunderts of reported items. I don't want to scroll up every time to see if all was ok.
Maybe a filter for the output window would help?

Maybe there is an option to ignore the first n leaks or to start reporting after a defined id?  If so, the number or Id could be adjusted every now and then as a first approach.